# UITextField difference between keystroke and copy/paste

Tags: ios, objective-c, input, uitextfield, uitextview

How can I find out whether user has typed a letter in a UITextField or copied from a source and pasted in UITextField?

Comment: Why do you need to know the difference?

Comment: Because I need to show a pop up when user paste content from a source not on a keystroke.

Answer (score 2):

You can sub class UITextField and override `paste` method. Whenever you paste anything in textfield that method will be triggered

```
-(void)paste:(id)sender{
    [super paste:sender];
    //set some flag so that you know that text is pasted  
}
```

Comment: And how can we inform viewcontroller or any datasource about it?

Comment: One way is obviously making another delegate lets say "PasteDelegate" of custom text field.